# Combining features conditions in a new property

Tags: wix

I have a Wix setupKit I have a few features that based on them some custom dialogs will be displayed. There are some conditions that I want to combine them in a new property. For example:

```
<Property Id="SERVERSETTINGSISNEEDED">
<![CDATA[(&Client = 3) OR (!Client = 3) OR (&CoreService = 3) OR (!CoreService = 3) OR (&ResourceService = 3) OR (!ResourceService = 3)]]>
</Property>
```

and then:

```
<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ServersSettingsDlg" Order="1">SERVERSETTINGSISNEEDED</Publish>
```

But it does not work and always show that dialog.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define an MSI property with the `<Property>` element in WiX, it is constructed at build time and you end up having a record in the [Property table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa370908.aspx) by the time MSI package is built. On the other hand, the feature states are resolved at run time, that is, when your package is being installed.

Hence, you try to reference runtime values during build time, which is not correct. I'm sure it can be explained why the resulting property evaluates to `true`, but that's not the question.

As far as I understand your question, you'd like to shorten the condition part of the element in order not to copy/paste the long string a number of times. If that's the case, you don't have to involve the MSI properties here - you can achieve this with WiX preprocessor feature.

So, do the following:

- define the condition as a preprocessor variable:

`<?define ServerSetingIsNeeded = "(&Client = 3) OR (!Client = 3) OR (&CoreService = 3) OR (!CoreService = 3) OR (&ResourceService = 3) OR (!ResourceService = 3)>"?>`

- use the variable instead of condition:

`<Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ServersSettingsDlg" Order="1">$(var.ServerSetingIsNeeded)</Publish>`